# C# String replace with dictionary and Regex condition

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary, replace, aggregate

I want to replace values of a string with a dictionary that I have but only if they comply a regex condition.

This is what I have:

```
string input = @"A.4 AND ([10] A.4 OR A.4) OR [10]A.4 A.5 [10]A.5";
Dictionary <string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
                                                    {"A.4", "Test"},
                                                    {"A.5", "Test2"},
                                                    };
var output = dict.Aggregate(input, (current, value) => current.Replace(value.Key, value.Value));

//current output = "Test AND ([10] Test OR Test) OR [10]Test Test2 [10]Test2"
//wished output = "Test AND ([10] A.4 OR Test) OR [10]A.4 Test2 [10]A.5"
```

I don't want to replace the text when there is `"[10]"` or `"[10] "` in front of the text. I think that I should use a regex or something similar but I don't know how.

Comment: You already mentioned a Regex. Have you tried using *Regex.Replace* instead of this? Or at least write a Regex that matches the parts you want?

Comment: What do the tags look like? If they have a pattern you could use it in a single regex, eg `(?<!\[10\]\s?)A\.\d+` would match all `A.n` values without the prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex to perform the replace operation:

```
var output = dict.Aggregate(input, (current, sub) => Regex.Replace(current, $@"(?<!\[10\]\s?){Regex.Escape(sub.Key)}", sub.Value));
```

The negative lookbehind assertion `(?<!\[10\]\s?)` will ensure the matched term never follows `[10]` or `[10]` .

---

As [Panagiotis Kanavos notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73958388/c-sharp-string-replace-with-dictionary-and-regex-condition/73958475?noredirect=1#comment130586568_73958475) you can skip the `Aggregate` call completely by passing a delegate that performs a dictionary lookup to `Regex.Replace`:

```
var replacePattern = $@"(?<!\[10\]\s?)(?:{string.Join('|', dict.Keys.Select(Regex.Escape))})";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, replacePattern, (m) =>  dict[m.Value]);
```

Comment: There's no need for `Aggregate`, at least for replacement. `Regex.Replace` has an overload with a delegate that returns the replacement value.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Good point, added to answer

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen Thank you so much, that totally worth for me. However I will use the solution with Aggregate because I have keys like (A.4 and A.41) and with the second solution the A.41 is not replaced with the correct value, it's replace with the A.4 value and then there is a 1 at the end. So I'm using the first one with dict.Reverse().Aggregate(... being dict a SortedDictionary so the longest keys will be checked first.

Comment: @EvilMorty add `\b` after the last `)` in `replacePattern` to fix that :)

Answer (score 1):

[Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) has an overload with a delegate that creates replacement values. If the tags have a pattern, a single regular expression can be used to match them and replace them using the dictionary values.

This regex matches tags in the form `A.n` where `n` a number:

```
var regex=new Regex(@"(?<!\[10\]\s?)A\.\d+");

var output=regex.Replace(input,match=>dict[match.Value]);

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

This produces

```
Test AND ([10] A.4 OR Test) OR [10]A.4 Test2 [10]A.5
```

`(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind pattern. It matches strings that *don't* start with the negated pattern. `(?<!\[10\]\s?)` matches strings that don't start with `[10]` and an optional space.